# Camel & CXF & REST: ERROR No message body writer has been found for class java.util.ArrayList, ContentType: application/json

Tags: spring, jackson, apache-camel, jax-rs, cxf

In my Spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="jacksonJsonProvider" class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider" />

<bean id="restJacksonProviderList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="jacksonJsonProvider"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

//......

<route id="RestMyRoute">
    <from id="RestRequest"  uri="cxfrs:/rest/MyService?resourceClasses=com.myself.services.MyService&amp;bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer&amp;providers=#restJacksonProviderList" />
    <to     uri="direct:doRoute" />
</route>
```

The Service interface:

```
@GET
@Path("/my/something/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name = "getSomethingResponse")
public List<MySomething> getSomething(
    @PathParam("id") @WebParam(name = "id") String id);
```

The code above works! I can send the get request to the URl and I get a JSON response.

Now, I do a small change: Instead of defining the web service's URL (and the route) by XML configuration, I define them by Java code:

```
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    private String uriRest = "cxfrs:/rest/MyService?resourceClasses=com.myself.services.MyService&amp;bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer&amp;providers=#restJacksonProviderList";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from(uriRest).
        to("log:input").
        to("direct:doRoute").
        to("log:output");       
    }   
}
```

When I hit the web service URL, I am getting `500 Internal Server Error` and in the logs (Tomcat) I see `JAXRSUtils                     ERROR No message body writer has been found for class java.util.ArrayList, ContentType: application/json`

Actually the debugger tells me that defining the URI by Java code is recognized, since I do hit the code inside the route.

I saw this error in many answers here, basically they say to add a Json provider and assign it to the CXF endpoint.

Seems to me like it is what I have done. But it does not work.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't use Camel so I don't understand this route building stuff, but the difference seems to be that with the xml, the provider list `restJacksonProviderList` is registered, while with Java it is not. That `JacksonJsonProvider` is what does the serializing. When that is not registered, there is no serilializer, and you get that error message saying no serializer (MessageBodyWriter) to handle the conversion. Like I said, I have no idea about any configurations, but the lack registration seems to be difference

Comment: Not clear - why doesn't the "providers=#restJacksonProviderList" at the end of `uriRest` register the providers in the list? This is what it is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As peeskillet said, it's because there isn't a list of providers registered under the name restJacksonProviderList. You can get the JndiContext like this and bind a list to it in the configure method of your routebuilder:

```
JndiContext registry = (JndiRegistry) context.getRegistry();
registry.bind("restJacksonProviderList", Arrays.asList(new JacksonJsonProvider()));
```

Edit after comments:
Change `&amp;` for `&` in your cxfrs uri definition, `&amp;` is only needed in xml.

Comment: First, which context is in your code? How do you get it? Second, I am not understanding what you are saying... "there isn't a list of providers registered under the name restJacksonProviderList" - there isn't? there is in the XML. Then in `from(uriRest)` I tell Camel to use these providers for this route. Not clear to me what I have in the XML that doesn't appear in the Java code. Clarification: in the Java version, I keep in the XML the registration of "restJacksonProviderList" and "jacksonJsonProvider" beans. I only change the **route** definition from XML to Java DSL.

Comment: Ah I see, try replacing the &amp; with just a & in your cxfrs endpoint.

Comment: Awesome! That was it. You saved the day. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit my answer to reflect what actually helped!